# not sending auth request in laravel echo server cli on server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, socket.io, laravel-echo

It works fine on local but does not work on server.

[my local image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdWnv.png)

[On the server image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSApG.png)

I use Laravel 5.8 and vuejs 
is domain https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved, the app.js file on the host was not Compiled correctly, and I uploaded it locally